# Handaling formatted Textbox like **/** or **/**** or **** **** **** **** something like that using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, text, box

Here `textbox` formats like `12/24 or 12/2024 or 2332 2432 4232 3324` etc.

Here `textbox` looks normal but when entering value it takes `/` and Space automatically When I try to enter 1224 using `sendKeys` its writing some junk values like `02/**` (** is empty)

Please provide me solution for this.

Here is my Textbox

[image]

Comment: Could you provided website url?? that's why we can test it in our end..

Comment: What is the framework you are using and which language you are automating?.Provide html code or snapshot of html or link to the webpage

Comment: Selenium WebDriver  using Java

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
string date = @"12/2016";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;        
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById("textboxID").value='" + date + "';");
```